# Htmlpurifier - allow textarea

Tags: html, htmlpurifier

How to enable `textarea` tags in [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org)?

I tried with:

```
  $config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'textarea');
```

But it doesnt work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Should work (from http://htmlpurifier.org/live/INSTALL). Do you call `$config->set()` at the right place?

Comment: Yes, it is at the right place, i put it where i put all other settings for HTMLPurifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

textarea is not supported unless you load the Forms module. This module gets loaded if you turn on %HTML.Trusted, but this directive also turns on JavaScript and should only be used for trusted users.